# Calculating cost for Azure databases

Tags: azure, azure-storage

I don't understand cost mechanisms for databasese in Azure: if I have three very small databases (10Mb each, 30Mb Total), do I spend more than having a single 2Gb db???
Thanks in advance... :-)
AB

Answer (score 2, accepted):

charges are per database, and total is based on the number of databases and their sizes, not the total of the sizes of all your databases. in the current pricing for your scenario above, the 2GB will be cheaper than the other three small databases.

Comment: Ok, at least now I know it! :-) Thanks!